# Reading element at index for vector pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, operators

So I have a function called foo which returns a

```
std::vector< std::string >*
```

I'm trying to call the function, then set an element from the returned vector. But I'm confused at why I can't just get the element at index using the [] operator.

These Work:

```
foo->at(0) = "hi";
(*foo())[0] = "hi";
foo()[0][0] = "hi";
```

But how come this gives me a 'no viable overloaded '='' error:

```
foo()[0] = "hi";
```

Comment: `foo()` is a `vector<string>*` so `foo()[0]` is a `vector<string>` and you cannot assign a `string` to a `vector<string>`?

Comment: I doubt `foo->at(0) = "hi";` compiles since `foo` is a function.

Comment: Having that return type is poor design in the first place

Answer (score 0):

operator= in vector library doesn’t use for insert sth, you can use push_back() or insert function to insert element like:

```
foo->push_back(“hi”); 
foo->insert(“hi”);
```

Answer (score -1):

This happens because of [array indexing](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/6-8a-pointer-arithmetic-and-array-indexing/)